# Is/Are there any leaderboard(s) in Pokemon Go?

Tags: pokemon-go

As I'm playing from an apk, I didn't find any (and wouldn't complain too.)

But, was wondering **whether there are any leaderboards (for the factions or users, etc) in Pokemon Go?**  (at least in the countries where it has launched *officially*)

Comment: The distribution of the teams would be interesting, too. Both locally and globally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this moment, leaderboards aren't in the game. But these kind of features may be implemented as part of an update later on.